# Indistinguishability from a low-quality source

Tags: compression, bitrate, psychoacoustics

Is there any way to estimate what bitrate would be required for a codec like vorbis or mp3 to achieve near transparency to a 10-bit, 32,768 Hz PCM source? Are there any heuristics that can be used to make an estimate *a priori*, or is an ABX test the only way to achieve this?

There is plenty of information that pertains to a more typical source such as 16-bit, 44.1 kHz PCM.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone has bothered to go for "near transparency" at that sort of quality, as it doesn't really have a use case - you master everything using the best quality you can, then you deliver in whatever the appropriate output may be. Highest quality mp3 or vorbis are considered to be good enough that humans don't hear issues with them. That said, I upvoted, as I'd like to know if this has been looked at :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - this question had a precursor on MSE [which I can't find now] where we kicked of a discussion. My problem is I haven't seen an audio file below 44.1k 16-bit since the 80s, so I don't even know where to start.